# Is it possible to build single rdlc file without creating the project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

Is it possible to build single rdlc file without creating the project in visual studio?

Comment: You seem to be a rookie.  take a tour of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Yes, you can use Report Builder 3.0 or 2016 depending on the version of your report server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Report Builder 3.0. My team never uses Visual Studio to create/edit reports.